# Prevent Fling on horizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-gesture

Hello fellow Android programmers !

I Have a HorizontalScrollView in a VerticalScrollView.

UX team decided to add a 'Fling' like action to quickly switch between screens. Now when we try to scroll the horizontal scroll the Fling is fired.

Any ideas how to prevent the Fling when the focus is on the horizontal scroll ?

Thanks

Ps, Code for the Fling Detector :

```
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString() +
        // event2.toString());

        int dx = (int) (event2.getX() - event1.getX());
        // don't accept the fling if it's too short
        // as it may conflict with a button push
        if (Math.abs(dx) > 250 && Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
            if (velocityX > 0) {

                swipeLeft();
            } else {
                if (isMenuShowing) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    swipeRight();
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)) {
        return true;
    }
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: then do not override onFling()/

Comment: The Fling is required. I want to prevent Fling when I'm touching the horizontal scroll view